# TypeScript and moment-transform with dynamically added function

Tags: javascript, function, typescript, momentjs

I'm using TypeScript and a moment.js plugin called ['moment-transform'](https://github.com/A----/moment-transform).

moment-transform dynamically adds a `transform` function to the moment object. Usage is something like this:

```
import moment = require('moment');
require('moment-transform'); // simply adds transform function

moment().transform('YYYY-MM-+07 00:00:00.000').toDate();
```

However, when building this with TypeScript, I get this error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'transform' does not exist on type 'Moment'.
```

How would I handle dynamically added functions properly?

[edit] `(moment() as any).transform('YYYY-MM-+07 00:00:00.000').toDate();` seems to work. Is this really the way to go? Is there any possibility to specify this globally??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the `moment` definitions using the following approach:

Declare any extensions to `moment` in your custom 'moment.d.ts':

```
import * as moment from "moment";

declare module "moment" 
{
    interface Moment 
    {
        transform(a: string): Moment;
    }
}
```

And consume it in your 'my.ts':

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

moment().transform('qw').toDate();
```

More on the matter: [Module Augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)